# 4 Digit Guessing Game Python

Tags: python

Im trying to make a 4 digit numbers guessing game in Python 3. It should work by generating a random number between 1000 and 10000 (random.range(1000,10000)) and then by the user guessing and it should return after each guess how many numbers you have got right. My code doesn't exactly work and, I can't think why it doesn't so help is appreciated.

```
import random as r

guessing = True
real_ans = r.randrange(1000, 10000, 2)
real_ans_str = str(real_ans)

correct = 0

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_guess = input("Enter a guess")
        self.evaluate(correct)
    def evaluate(self, correct):
        for n in range(3):
            if self.player_guess[n] == real_ans_str[n]:
                correct += 1
        if not correct == 4:
            print(str(correct)," was correct")
            correct = 0
        else:
            print("You guessed it! ")
            guessing = False

while guessing:
    Player()
```

Comment: Why did you implement a class like a method?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want the user to input an integer?

Comment: Can't explain it... Run the code in IDLE then you'll get what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: Are you trying to guess individual numbers one at a time? Or are you entering 4 digit numbers and want to check that 4 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You're creating a new instance of Player class inside the main loop. It works, but it's not the best approach IMHO.
2. You're using `guessing` to stop the main loop. In Python, all variables are local by default. In order to reference a global variable, you must identify it as global:

```
def evaluate(self, correct):
    **global guessing**
    for n in range(3):
        if self.player_guess[n] == real_ans_str[n]:
            correct += 1
    if not correct == 4:
        print(str(correct)," was correct")
        correct = 0
    else:
        print("You guessed it! ")
        guessing = False
```

However using global variables could lead to a messy code.

3. range provides values from the minimum (0 by default) inclusive and the maximum exclusive. That range(3) will provide the numbers 0, 1 and 2 (3 numbers total), which is not what you want.

Since you're using a class, I'd try the following:

1. Create a single instance of Player
2. Create a new method called guess
3. Change the evaluate method to return how many digits the player guessed right
4. Create a new method called run, that will call guess and evaluate

```
import random as r

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.real_ans = str(r.randrange(1000,100000,2))

    def guess(self):
        self.player_guess = raw_input("Enter a guess")

    def evaluate(self):
        correct = 0
        for n in range(4):
            if self.player_guess[n] == self.real_ans[n]:
                correct += 1
        return correct 

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.guess()
            correct = self.evaluate()
            if not correct == 4:
                print(str(correct)," was correct")
            else:
                print("You guessed it! ")
                break

Player().run()
```

Comment: Yes thats much better than what I had. Does make much more sense thanks :)

Comment: I replaced the input with raw_input. It's the right way to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
#Digit Guessing Game by Deniz
#python 3.5.1 - Please note that from Python version 2.7 "Tkinter" has been renamed tkinter, with a lowercase "t".
import tkinter
import random

computer_guess = random.randint(1,10)

def check():

    user_guess = int(txt_guess.get())


if user_guess < computer_guess:
    msg = "Higher!"
elif user_guess > computer_guess:
    msg = "Lower!"
elif user_guess == computer_guess:
    msg = "Correct!"
else:
    msg = "Houston we have a problem!..."


lbl_result["text"] = msg


txt_guess.delete(0, 5)

def reset():

    global computer_guess
    computer_guess = random.randint(1,10)
    lbl_result["text"] = "Game reset. Guess again!"

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.configure(bg="white")

root.title("Guess the correct number!")

root.geometry("280x75")

lbl_title = tkinter.Label(root, text="Welcome to Deniz's guessing Game!", bg="White")
lbl_title.pack()

lbl_result = tkinter.Label(root, text="Good Luck!", bg="White")
lbl_result.pack()

btn_check = tkinter.Button(root, text="Check", fg="blue", bg="White", command=check)
btn_check.pack(side="left")

btn_reset = tkinter.Button(root, text="Reset", fg="red", bg="White", command=reset)
btn_reset.pack(side="right")

txt_guess = tkinter.Entry(root, width=7)
txt_guess.pack()

root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: Try the above, which uses the tkinter GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Use `range(4)`, `range(3)` has the values `[0, 1, 2]` so `3` is missing:

```
for n in range(4):
    if self.player_guess[n] == real_ans_str[n]:
        correct += 1
```

The global `guessing` is not available inside the class method, so the loop never ends after guessing it right.

And working but ugly solution would be:

```
print("You guessed it! ")
global guessing
guessing = False
```

Comment: I did that but I get: Enter a guess1400
3  was correct
Enter a guess1401
2  was correct
Enter a guess1400
3  was correct
Enter a guess1440
2  was correct

Comment: print(str(correct)," was correct") change this to print(real_ans_str," was correct") and self.player_guess = input("Enter a guess") to self.player_guess = str(input("Enter a guess"))

Comment: @Sagar: It should show how many digits are correct so `print(str(correct), "was correct")` should be right

Comment: @GüntherJena: sorry about that, OP had posted "it should return after each guess how many numbers you have got right", got confused

Comment: There are inconsistencies. For example you guess 1400: 3 right, then 1401: 2 right, then 1440: 2 right. That can't be right??

Comment: @GeorgeBaker: your entries with 1400, 1401 and 1440 doesn't seem to show a wrong result. You have to guess further

Comment: @GeorgeBaker: You think the the first two have to be right? I think that's not the case

Comment: @GeorgeBaker: Change the print to `print(str(correct)," was correct ...", real_ans_str)` for debugging purpose.

Comment: Yes turns out your right. I however, how do I get the loop to end?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I think what you need is this:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_guess = input("Enter a guess")
        self.evaluate(correct)
    def evaluate(self, correct):
        for n in range(4):
            if self.player_guess[n] == real_ans_str[n]:
                correct += 1
            else:
               print(str(correct)," was correct")
               correct = 0
               break
        if correct == 4:
            print("You guessed it! ")
            guessing = False
```

You can integrate it along with @Robson's answer to end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non infinite loop version without a class. I assumed you wanted to input one number at a time? If not, that could be changed.

Also, the 2 on the end of the `randrange` only included even numbers, so that wasn't necessary

```
import random as r
debug = True

real_ans = str(r.randrange(1000, 10000))

if debug:
    print(real_ans) 

correct = 0
for i in range(len(real_ans)):
    player_guess = input("Enter a guess: ")
    if str(player_guess) == real_ans[i]:
        correct += 1

if correct == 4:
    print('You guessed it!')
    correct = 0
else:
    print('Sorry!', real_ans, 'was correct')
```

Sample run (Correct)

```
9692
Enter a guess: 9
Enter a guess: 6
Enter a guess: 9
Enter a guess: 2
You guessed it!
```

Sample run (Incorrect)

```
4667
Enter a guess: 5
Enter a guess: 5
Enter a guess: 5
Enter a guess: 5
Sorry! 4667 was correct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input
x= random.randint(1000,9999)
num=0
while num < 1000 or num > 9999:
    num = int(raw_input("Please enter a 4 digit number: "))
    if num < 1000 or num > 9999:
        print("///wrong input////")

print("system generated number is ",x)
print("The number you entered is ",num)
if num == x:
    print("Congrats you win")
else:
    rabbit=0
    tortose=0
    unum = str(num)
    snum = str(x)
    c1=0enter code here
    for i in unum:
        c1=c1+1
        c2 = 0
        for j in snum:
            c2=c2+1
            if(i==j):
                if(c1==c2):
                    rabbit=1

                else:
                    tortose=1


    if rabbit==1:
        print("you got rabbit")
    elif rabbit==0 and tortose==1:
        print("you got tortose")
    else:
        print("Bad Luck you dont have any match")

    enter code here
```

Comment: Code only answers like this tends to be downvoted on this site. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65482915/edit) it to explain how and why it solves op question.

Answer (score 0):

what i did was just change `n` from `n in range(3)` to `n in range(4)` in line 14

```
import random as r

guessing = True
real_ans = r.randrange(1000, 10000, 2)
real_ans_str = str(real_ans)

correct = 0

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_guess = input("Enter a guess")
        self.evaluate(correct)
    def evaluate(self, correct):
        for n in range(4):
            if self.player_guess[n] == real_ans_str[n]:
                correct += 1
        if not correct == 4:
            print(str(correct)," was correct")
            correct = 0
        else:
            print("You guessed it! ")
            guessing = False

while guessing:
    Player()
```