# Guess 4 digit combination game

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am trying a similar thing like this: [4 Digit Guessing Game Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801677/4-digit-guessing-game-python) . With little changes.

The program generates random numbers between 999 and 10000.User after every failed attempt gets how many numbers he guess in the right spot and how many numbers he got right but didn't guess position correctly.
Etc. a random number is 3691 and the user guess is 3619. He gets 2 numbers in the correct position (3 and 6) and also 2 numbers correct but in the wrong position (1 and 9).

There is no output when for numbers he didn't guess and guessing is repeating until all 4 digits are guessed in the right spot.

My idea is we save digits of the random number to a list and then do the same thing with user guess number. Then we compare the first item of both lists etc. `combination_list[0] == guess_ist[0]` and if it's correct we add +1 on counter we call `correct`.

The problem is I don't have an idea for numbers that are guessed correctly but are not in the correct position.

```
import random
combination = random.randint(1000, 9999)
print(combination)

digits_combination, digits_guess= [], []
temp = combination

while temp > 0:
    digits_combination.append(temp % 10)
    temp //= 10

digits_combination.reverse()
print(digits_combination)

guess= int(input("Your numbers are? "))
while not 999 < pokusaj < 10000:
    pokusaj = int(input("Your numbers are? "))

if guess!= combination:
    while guess> 0:
        digits_guess.append(guess% 10)
        guess//= 10
    digits_guess.reverse()

if guess == combination:
    print("Your combination is correct.")

correct_position= 0
correct= 0
test = digits_combination[:] # I copied the list here

while guess!= combination:
    while guess> 0:
        digits_guess.append(guess% 10)
        guess //= 10
    digits_guess.reverse()

    if digits_guess[0] == test[0]:
        correct_position += 1
```

Comment: You can count it `if combination_list[i] != guess_list[i] and guest_list[i] in combination_list:` if no digit is duplicate. For duplicate digits, it maybe depend on how you define for not in the correct position. You can get list by `list(str(number)), then compare each character.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution. I suggestion you to cast to string and after cast to list to get a list of number digits instead to use a while loop. For the question you can try to use "in" keywords to check if number in digits_combination but not in right position.

```py
import random
combination = random.randint(1000, 9999)
print(combination)

digits_combination = list(str(combination))

guess= int(input("Your numbers are? "))
while not 999 < guess < 10000:
    guess = int(input("Your numbers are? "))

digits_guess = list(str(guess))

if guess == combination:
    print("Your combination is correct.")

correct_position = 0
correct = 0
for index, value in enumerate(digits_guess):
  if value == digits_combination[index]:
    correct_position += 1
  elif value in digits_combination:
    correct += 1
```

Comment: You don't need to convert to `list`s: you can use the strings directly. Also, you don't need to convert the user input to `int`: just check `"1000" <= guess <= "9999`. More important, how do you deal with duplicate digits? Suppose the combination is "1234" and the guess is "5116"